# ExtractingRequestHandler - how do you post multi-valued literal fields?

Tags: solr, apache-tika, solr-cell

I'm trying to post a literal, multi-valued field along with a PDF extract. Only one of the field values seems to be being added to the index. Does this need to be passed in a different way?

Currently sending equivalent of (via POST values):

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?literal.keyword_txt=keyword1&literal.keyword_txt=keyword2&literal.keyword_txt=keyword3...etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Input_Parameters) Wiki Page about Input Parameters, it supports multivalued literals.

> literal.= - Create a field with the specified value.
>   May be multivalued if the Field is multivalued.

I would think that you should pass the multivalued liertal as comma separated values. So perhaps try the following:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?
      literal.keyword_txt=keyword,keyword2,keyword3
```

Comment: I thought I'd already tried that, but I just tried again and it seems to have worked. Thanks!

Comment: Solr 4.3.0 gives "Error adding field for input string"

Comment: Also, i doubt it ever worked, as comma separated strings parsing into e.g integers would be quite challenging (think about thousands separators, different cultures, etc)

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same and found a different solution:

```
... literal.id_section=1&literal.id_section=2 ...
```

This worked for me.

The field is defined as follows:

```
<field name="id_section"  type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Versions:

- apache-solr-1.4.1
- tomcat 6

Bye
LB

Comment: Solr 4.3.0, works perfectly, and looking at docs i think it's the only valid way to achieve this. +1